# horizontally sub menu should slide content down

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, css-position

I have some issues with my horizontal menu. The main content should avoid the sub menu. So when the sub menu opens it should shove the main content down.

The html

```html
<ul id="menu">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Menu2</a>
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

and the css

```css
#menu{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;  
    background: #111;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    min-width: 1100px;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    text-align:center;

}

#menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#menu a{
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 50px 0 0;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 12px/25px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
    height: 30px;
    }

#menu li:hover > a{
    color: #fafafa;
}

*html #menu li a:hover{ /* IE6 */
    color: #fafafa;
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

/* Sub-menu */

#menu ul{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0 0 0;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;  
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #111;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    min-width: 1100px;
}

}

#menu ul li{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    position: relative;
}

#menu ul a{    
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0px 25px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 12px/25px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

#menu ul a:hover{
        background: #0186ba;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);    
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04acec), to(#0186ba));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
    background: linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
}
/* Clear floated elements */
#menu:after{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

* html #menu             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html #menu { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

I tried to change the `#menu ul` position to relative. But that messes up the whole style.
Anybody who likes to help me? =)

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/M8S3T/

Answer (score 0):

The elements that are absolutely or fixed positioned are removed from the normal flow of the page. You must avoid `position:absolute` if you want to preserve the flow.

I try to make a quick example to show: http://jsfiddle.net/M8S3T/1/

```
#menu li{
    float:left;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0; 
    width:5em;
}


/* Sub-menu */

#menu ul{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 40px -80px 0;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;  
    display: none;
    background: #111;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    min-width: 1100px;
}

#menu li ul li {
    float:left;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    width: 10em;
}

#menu ul a{    
    float: none;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0px 25px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 12px/25px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}
```

I only post you the parts I have changed. With this you can play with the `float`, and if you use a fixed width for the list items it will work.